# У меня не получается открыть 2 разных окошка Offcanvas.При нажатии на 2 окошко открывается 1 окно.Использую bootstrap v.5

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap

```
<section class="p-3 m-0 border-0 bd-example m-0 border-0">
    <button
      class="btn btn-primary"
      type="button"
      data-bs-toggle="offcanvas"
      data-bs-target="#offcanvasExample"
      aria-controls="offcanvasExample"
      style="width: 3%; padding: 2px; background: white; border: 0"
    >
      <a class="block max-w-max" href="#" style="color: blue">
        <svg
          width="24"
          height="24"
          viewBox="0 0 24 24"
          fill="none"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          data-config-id="auto-svg-5-2"
        >
          <path
            d="M19 4H5C4.20435 4 3.44129 4.31607 2.87868 4.87868C2.31607 5.44129 2 6.20435 2 7V17C2 17.7956 2.31607 18.5587 2.87868 19.1213C3.44129 19.6839 4.20435 20 5 20H19C19.7956 20 20.5587 19.6839 21.1213 19.1213C21.6839 18.5587 22 17.7956 22 17V7C22 6.20435 21.6839 5.44129 21.1213 4.87868C20.5587 4.31607 19.7956 4 19 4ZM5 6H19C19.2652 6 19.5196 6.10536 19.7071 6.29289C19.8946 6.48043 20 6.73478 20 7L12 11.88L4 7C4 6.73478 4.10536 6.48043 4.29289 6.29289C4.48043 6.10536 4.73478 6 5 6ZM20 17C20 17.2652 19.8946 17.5196 19.7071 17.7071C19.5196 17.8946 19.2652 18 19 18H5C4.73478 18 4.48043 17.8946 4.29289 17.7071C4.10536 17.5196 4 17.2652 4 17V9.28L11.48 13.85C11.632 13.9378 11.8045 13.984 11.98 13.984C12.1555 13.984 12.328 13.9378 12.48 13.85L20 9.28V17Z"
            fill="currentColor"
          ></path>
        </svg>
      </a>
    </button>

    <div
      class="offcanvas offcanvas-start"
      tabindex="-1"
      id="offcanvasExample"
      aria-labelledby="offcanvasExampleLabel"
    >
      <div class="offcanvas-header-2">
        <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasExampleLabel">
          Сообщения
        </h5>
        <button
          type="button"
          class="btn-close"
          data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas"
          aria-label="Закрыть"
        ></button>
      </div>
      <div class="offcanvas-body-2">
        <div class="">Сообщений нет.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: В Бутстрапе модальные окна открываются по id: у кнопки есть параметр `data-bs-target`, который соответствует id окна (в Вашем примере это `offcanvasExample`). Если id двух окон совпадают, то открываться всегда будет только первое. Сделайте разные id у окон offcanvas и, соответственно, разные data-bs-target у кнопок.

Comment: Спасибо! Все сработало